# Query all friends in a network

Tags: facebook

Is there any way to retrieve all friends in a particular network? For example, How can I view the list of my Facebook friends joined the network of my organization.

Comment: Untagged as `facebook-connect`; not a practical application for FBC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write an FQL query such as this:

```
SELECT uid, name FROM user WHERE affiliations.nid = <your network id>
```

The problem is that affiliations are not indexable, so you would need to have a constraint on either the `username`, `name`, or `uid` column(s) (which kind of defeats the purpose).

So the moral of the story is that if you know the ID of the user or are able to generate a range of users, then you can fetch this data. Otherwise, Facebook pukes on you.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think you can say

```
SELECT uid, name
FROM user
WHERE
  affiliations.nid = [your network id]
  AND uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=[your user id])
```