# Getting members of a facebook group

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk, facebook-c#-sdk

Anyone know how to list all members of a facebook group? I'm trying to get "/groupid/members", but that only returns *one*...

Cheers!

Comment: I am trying to figure this out too. Anyone? How about a facebook network (this doesn't seem possible per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442023/query-all-friends-in-a-network).

Answer (score 0):

```
        var fb = new FacebookWebClient();

        dynamic result = fb.Get("[GroupID OR Name]/members");

        ViewBag.Members= result.data;
```

Comment: This has been deprecated as of Apr 2018 you can use /opted-in-users